# How can I run EntityFramework 7 tests?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I followed the steps [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Getting-and-Building-the-Code) and have EntityFramework 7 building in VS2015.

Under *RunTests* the instructions above note the following:

> Our tests are written using [xUnit.net 2.0](https://github.com/xunit/xunit), and can be run using your
>   favorite runner. We recommend either the built-in Visual Studio test
>   runner or [TestDriven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/).

In VS2015, executing *Test > Run > All Tests* results in:

```
------ Discover test started ------
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.0990702) ==========
```

Taking a look at [Running xUnit.net tests in Visual Studio](http://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-vs.html) reveals that you need to:

> Search for (and install) a package named `xunit.runner.visualstudio`

However doing so results in a failed install, for either the current stable or prerelease package;

```
Resolving conflicts for DNXCore,Version=v5.0...
Unable to find a version of package 'System.Dynamic.Runtime' that is compatible with version constraint '[4.0.0, )'.
Unable to find a version of package 'System.Text.RegularExpressions' that is compatible with version constraint '[4.0.10, )'.
Unable to find a version of package 'System.ComponentModel' that is compatible with version constraint '[4.0.0, )'.
Unable to find a version of package 'System.IO.FileSystem' that is compatible with version constraint '[4.0.0, )'.
Unable to find a version of package 'System.Collections.Concurrent' that is compatible with version constraint '[4.0.0, )'.
========== Finished ==========
  NotFound https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.framework.primitives/index.json 1078ms
```

How can I run the tests without a TestDriven.Net license?

Comment: Do you have the correct nuget.config entires?

Comment: @ErikEJ they are [unchanged](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/NuGet.Config)

Comment: I am able to repro, this should be made to work, suggest you file a bug report here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/new

Comment: @ErikEJ cheers, have [done](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3121).